# Find the minimum value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, if $(x,y,z)$ are perpendiculars drawn from any interior point P of a triangle ABC on the sides BC, CA and AB

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $(x,y,z)$ be the lengths of perpendiculars drawn from any interior point P of a triangle ABC on the sides BC, CA and AB respectively, then find the minimum value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$. The sides-lengths  of the triangle $ABC$ being $a$, $b$ and $c$.

**My try**

I have found that the area of the triangle would be $\frac{ax+by+cz}{2}$. 
So that can form a constraint equation. Can I go ahead and minimise $x^2+y^2+z^2$ with the constraint ${ax+by+cz}=K$(some constant) using Lagrange's multiplier method? Would that be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(ax+by+cz)^2=4S^2.$$
Thus, $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq\frac{2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4}{4(a^2+b^2+c^2)}.$$
The equality occurs for $(x,y,z)||(a,b,c)$, which says that we got a minimal value.

We'll prove that there exist $P$ inside the triangle for which $x:y:z=a:b:c$.

Let $L\in AB$ such that $\frac{S_{\Delta LBC}}{S_{\Delta LAC}}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ and   $M\in AC$ such that $\frac{S_{\Delta MBC}}{S_{\Delta MAC}}=\frac{a^2}{c^2}$.

Now, let $BM\cap CL=\{K\}$ and easy to see that for this $K$ we get an equality case.

Comment: should it be $b^2c^2$?

Comment: It was typo. Thank you!

Comment: hello Michael, Problem solving on the Weekend?

Comment: Hello! For me it happens always.

Comment: for me it happens also

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @user467745 You are welcome!

Comment: How do you prove that $(x, y, z) || (a, b, c)$ is possible?

Comment: @Gribouillis I added something. See now please.

Comment: Thank you, I'll work on  the *easy to see* part.

Answer (score 1):

hint: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is the tool: $K^2 = (ax+by+cz)^2 \le (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$...Can you continue?